# Knex: How to express "SELECT genre, count(*) FROM films GROUP BY genre;"?

Tags: sql, node.js, group-by, count, knex.js

Using latest node, knex:

I want to do a simple standard SQL count & group by query to find the number of films in each genre from a flat table:

```
SELECT genre, count(*) FROM films GROUP BY genre;
```

... using the node query-builder knex, but I can't see that particular simple use case in the documentation.

I can do it with `knex.raw()` - but I'd like to know how to do it with the standard query builder if possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: hi there Chris! in case your query is ran against bigquery, which I assumed since you said standardSQL, have you checked this? https://github.com/avian-aero/knex-bigquery

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is interested, it seems to be:

```
knex.select('genre').from('films').count().groupBy('genre');
```

I didn't find any examples that combined count & groupBy...